# HOW TO RETURN FULL DATA BUT UNIQUE IN CERTAIN FIELD

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this example data

```
[
{id:1, type:"A", date:2022-01-01},
{id:2, type:"A", date:2022-01-02},
{id:3, type:"B", date:2022-01-01}
]
```

But how to get only one data per each type, like i have to get the output like this.

```
[
{id:2, type:"A", date:2022-01-02},
{id:3, type:"B", date:2022-01-01}
]
```

get only one data if have a same type value.
i've tried $group $first but none work.
any guys can help me?
what should i code in mongodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what not worked for you, but `$group` and `$first` (or `$last`) is the way to go, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$type",
      root: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$root"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3L38qEGYpSy)